# What is wrong with my vector 3 speed-cap formula?

Tags: gdscript

3D movement. If the player moves left-backwards, they will go at double the speed of any other direction. MoveDirection.x and z are equal to the respective analog stick directions, ranging from 1 to -1.

```
MoveDirection = Vector3(MoveDirection.x - (MoveDirection.z / 2 * MoveDirection.x), MoveDirection.y, MoveDirection.z - (MoveDirection.x / 2 * MoveDirection.z))
```

I thought that the results would be something like 0.5, 0, 0.5 if moving diagonally but that isn't the case.

Comment: Sorry, just wondering, you mentioned that `MoveDirection.x`, and `MoveDirection.z`, are the analog values (-1 to 1), what is the value of `MoveDirection.y`? Also, what are the results you are getting?

Comment: The results are  normal if you go in any direction other than left-down. If it's left down the speed is doubled. The vector is representative of the direction you are going, say (0.5, 0, 0.5) (it can be negative values) when it works, and when it doesn't it's either slightly off or about double speed. Movedireection.y is your upwards and downwards movement like jumping and gravity and is handled somewhere else, and isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it doesn't also occur in the right-backwards direction as well? I'm thinking that this could likely be be related to how Godot handles arithmetic order.  For example, if Godot does multiplication before division (like I think it does), then assuming we use whole values (1 or -1), then Godot would process the first Vector3 coordinate in your code this way::

```
Using - (MoveDirection.x - (MoveDirection.z / 2 * MoveDirection.x)
Substitute values for - (x,z)

FOR VALUES  (1 , -1)
(1) - (-1 / (2 * 1))
(1) - (-1) / (2)
(1) - (-0.5)
= 1.5       <<<<<<-----------    THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM (I THINK)

FOR VALUES  (-1, 1)
(-1) - (1 / (2 * -1))
(-1) - (1) / (-2)
(-1) - (-0.5)
= -0.5

FOR VALUES   (1 , 1)
(1) - (1 / (2 * 1))
(1) - (1) / (2)
(1) - (0.5)
= 0.5

FOR VALUES  (-1, -1)
(-1) - (-1 / (2 * -1))
(-1) - (-1) / (-2)
(-1) - (0.5)
= -1.5       <<<<<<-----------    THIS SHOULD ALSO BE A PROBLEM (I THINK)
```

If my math is wrong, please forgive me, it's 5:00AM where I am. If I am wrong, let me know and I'll delete this answer.

EDIT: It turns out arithmetic order doesn't even matter, it does the same thing with division first. My suggestion would be to find a way to subtract 1 from (or add 1 to) the affected results. Maybe something like: `if (MoveDirection.x > 0) AND (MoveDirection.z < 0)`, subtract 1 from result.

Comment: I think I understand the problem thanks to your trace table thingy. Doubly subtracting  results in a positive, so my solution was along the lines of:   
MoveDirection.x - (MoveDirection.z / 2 * (MoveDirection.x / MoveDirection.x) 
But this means if the stick is neutral then I get a div by 0 error. Not sure what I can do from here, because the godot normalization method doesnt work the way I want either. For now I have just done "if speed is over 1, div both directions by 1.5" which works but results in a speed that isn't quite consistent. 
The answer doesn't have to be deleted, its helpful.

Comment: Ok. i'll leave it up. I will also continue to look for a solution, as I'll likely need to know something like this in the future (I'm assuming you're trying to negate a strafe-run speed doubling effect - a classic challenge in first person movement). I know in many situations you can use min()  and max() methods to clamp the values between -1 and 1, but i'm not yet sure how to implement that in Godot. Maybe you can figure it out. Something like `MoveDirection.z = max(MoveDirection.x, 1.0)` I also think (though i'm not sure) you can use these methods to make sure the values are never 0.

Comment: Actually, nevermind the last 2 lines in my last comment - I used x and z when they both should have been the same- but that doesn't matter, because you don't want to clamp the value of MoveDirection anyway, instead, you need to clamp the first and third Vector3 coordinates - not sure how to do that

Comment: From what I've gathered from reading up on the subject, Vectors are generally normalized in order to keep their values from exceeding 1. However, since the resulting values are either 1 or -1, this will not work well for analog inputs. For analog, I think you can achieve what you want by adding something like this after the vector calculation: `if MoveDirection.length() > 1: MoveDirection = MoveDirection / MoveDirection.length()`. You might need to multiply the resulting value by delta (not sure).